# Connect webparts using CSOM C# or Powershell - Connected Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, jsom, connected-web-parts

I have two SharePoint Lists `Departments` and `Users` in SharePoint Online. Users list have lookup of Department Title.

I want to add List View of `Users` to Display Form (DispForm.aspx) of `Departments`. So that when I click on any department then below the display form, it will display users of that department. I have successfully implemented it manually.

Now I want to make **connection between both webparts using any client side solution** available (CSOM C#, Powershell, JSOM) for SharePoint Online. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the API supports this at the moment, but I'll be happy to be proven otherwise.

"At the moment it does not seem possible to create WebPart connections via the Client Side Object Model."

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147039-add-csom-support-for-connected-webparts

Dev team "thinking about it" since May 4 2017.

Also, duplicate of (unanswered) [Create a web part connection via client API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118125/create-a-web-part-connection-via-client-api)